Difference between "blow a fuse/gasket", "fly off the handle" and "hit the ceiling/roof"
Are there any differences in the meaning of or when we use the idioms 'blow a fuse/gasket', 'fly off the handle' or 'hit the ceiling/roof'? The definitions in the Cambridge Dictionary are:

blow a fuse/gasket: to become very angry
fly off the handle: to react in a very angry way to something that someone says or does
hit the ceiling/roof: to become extremely angry


They all mean the same.

Believe Michael Harvey here, and ask yourself why there was a Question… What difference did you see in those Cambridge definitions?

'Blow a fuse/gasket' and 'hit the ceiling roof' (also 'go up the wall') carry the same meaning. The fact that their dictionary definitions are not word-for-word the same is not significant. True, the different adverbs used in the definitions, 'extremely' and 'very', are usually seen as implying differing intensities, but as the idioms in question are both extremely hyperbolic they are already highly exaggerated.
Fly off the handle is used slightly differently - it does contain that reactionary element that suggests the subject is maybe hypersensitive, has perhaps misunderstood something, or is overreacting. The other idioms don't suggest this quite so much and could be used to say that someone has legitimate cause to be angry.

I'd add that fly off the handle hints at a verbal reaction more than the other two, which suggest feeling overwhelmed with or without an angry outburst.

I dated a girl from Glasgow when I was 20, and she called it 'throwing an epi'.

@MichaelHarvey Yes, that's a slang shortening of 'epileptic fit', and unsurprisingly is considered an offensive, ableist slur today.

@Astralbee - it was in 1982, and I told her that.

@Astralbee - it was all the more annoying since my father suffered from epilepsy.
